# Jupyter Notebook remote browser without disconnecting

Tags: python, ssh, jupyter-notebook, remote-access

I'm running a jupyter notebook remotely on a server by

1. connecting to the server: `ssh server:address`
2. initialize the jypter notebook `ipython notebook --no-browser --port=7000`
3. using another terminal window, stabilish remove connection to the notebook `ssh -N -f -L localhost:6001:localhost:7000 server:address`
4. finally I access it throw `localhost:6001` in my browser.

The thing is: **I'd like to keep the notebook running when I turn my computer off**. Any ideas on how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a **crontab** on your remote server with your command **ipython notebook --no-browser --port=7000** to manage the execution of Jupiter notebook, that could be the way go.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command to start the jupyter notebook using [`nohup`](https://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/) on the remote terminal or in a [screen session](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/) so that the process is not killed when you close the session.

For example, you can run the following command in a remote shell:

```sh
nohup ipython notebook --no-browser --port=7000 > jupyter.out 2>&1 &
```

The above command redirects the standard output and standard error to the file `jupyter.log`, so that you can inspect and analyze the output of your command.